# Can I accept a job offer in the UK if I am a non-eu spouse (US Citizen) married to an EU Citizen?

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-spouses

I am a US Citizen currently living in the EU with my EU Citizen wife but may have a job offer in the UK. Is it possible to accept that job offer if I am not currently living in the UK with a UK Residence permit? From my understanding it would not be a problem for me to work in the UK if my wife received a job offer or was a job seeker living in the UK. Is it possible for me to accept that job offer and if so what would the process be?

Comment: Have the firm trying to employ you checked your right to work in the UK yet ? Normally an offer isn't issued unless they are able to confirm if you have the right to work in UK.

Comment: They asked me to check with UK Immigration to find out what the process is. I plan to contact them  tomorrow but I wanted to see if I could get an idea of the process from here (if there is even one). They will need to verify with immigration themselves of course but I think they were more concerned with the timeline involved.

Comment: You can work in the UK if you live there with your wife. There are some formalities required but they should be relatively straightforward while the UK remains in the EU. Are the two of you planning to move there together?

Comment: If i were to get a job offer I would move there with my wife. But I am not currently in the UK which is my concern.

Comment: If you would be moving to the UK with your wife to take the job, what does it matter whether you are there now?

Comment: I hope it does not matter thats my primary motivation for asking this question.

Comment: There could be holes in the British employment-authorization scheme that don't take your case into consideration; I'm not familiar enough with the scheme to know.  But even if there are, it shouldn't matter.  As long as you don't start working before your wife gets to the UK, you are fine.  Strictly speaking, you don't even need to get your residence documents before you start working.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you could not *accept* the offer. Whether your wife moves there first and you are joining her, you have a job lined up from the start or you find a job after entering the UK, your rights as the spouse of an EU citizen and the procedure to follow are, for the time being, more-or-less the same.

For you to be able to use that route however your wife must (come to) live in the UK with you. Otherwise, your status would be completely different. And if your wife does not work at all, there are some restrictions (see e.g. [Options for EU person to move to Spain without a having secured apriori a job](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7138/options-for-eu-person-to-move-to-spain-without-a-having-secured-apriori-a-job/7144#7144)).